# How to access Bixby profile information (first name/last name) inside Input-View

Tags: bixby

I want to access the user info in the result- and input-view to make a message like that
**"Thanks [Username] for you sharing"**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can access time in the input-view using now().time function, So i tried to import contact and self libraries but i don't know how to access to them inside the input-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume result-view is easy, so I include an example here for input-view.

The challenge here is to render the [username] which is not part of the input value. The solution is to group these two values together with an action.

```
input-view {
  match: IntAge(this) {
    to-input: GetStructPerson (action)
  }
  message {
    template ("Enter age of #{value(action.name)}")
  }
  render {
    form {
      elements {
        number-input {
          id (that)
          label (Age)
          type (IntAge) 
        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal: IntAge
        value: viv.core.FormElement(that)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Action is nothing but a constructor

```
action (GetStructPerson) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  type (Constructor) 
  collect {
    input (name) {
      type (TextName)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (age) {
      type (IntAge) 
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (StructPerson)
}
```

I think this is the similar render result you want. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

User information is present in $vivContext which is accessible to the developer in the corresponding javascript file of an Action. One way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to create a hidden property in your structure (called in the result-view) called `userName` and use an Action `FillUserName` to populate this property.

The following resources will help too. Good luck!

- https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information
- https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/user-context